# How to show text over the image when user type in text box?

Tags: javascript, image

Heres the example:
http://www.potterybarn.com/products/saddle-stitch-leather-luggage-tag/?catalogId=69&cm_src=AutoRel

when user type some text in 'See how your personalization would look on this item. Specify text:'
and press preview than that text appears on image with some specific font style n all.
so the question is how to do this ? is this a JavaScript ? and if yes than from where should i get this ?

Comment: I want to implement this code..but i don't know how to do this ??

Comment: As of now, i don't know from where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then take idea from this

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function preview()
{
document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=document.getElementById("person").value;
}</script></head>
<body>
<div style="position:relative;">
<img src="whatever"><span id="txt" style="font:20px Tahoma;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;"></span>
</div>
<label for="person">See how your personalization would look on this item. Specify text:</label><input type="text" id="person" >
<button onclick="preview()">Preview</button></body></html>
```

Comment: don't know why people forget to comment with downvoting

Comment: if it worked for you then don't forget to click on the check mark at the left side of this answer